# What locking rules config should I use on my Plastic Cloud server for my Unreal project?

Tags: version-control, unreal-engine4, plasticscm

I have an Unreal Engine 4 project that I want to check into a Plastic Cloud repository. I need to set up locking rules for the cloud repository, but I'm not sure what the best thing to put there is?

Answer (score 0):

So far I've put together this ruleset, which forces all file types to be locked, but then excludes some commonly mergable filetypes, but it still feels like I'm leaving out a lot of things that could be mergeable.

```
*
!*.cs
!*.txt
!*.README
!*.conf 
!*.ini
!*.c
!*.h
!*.cpp
```

Comment: The UE plugin for Plastic SCM includes a section for locking items. Only the binary assets should be locked for exclusive access to avoid merge conflicts. To lock all assets, you need to include the "Content" directory: https://github.com/SRombauts/UE4PlasticPlugin

Comment: What do you mean by "includes a section for locking items"? As far as I can tell, it provides the ability to lock files, but does not configure Plastic Cloud to require locks for any file types.

Comment: I meant that the plugin has support for showing and handling the locks. The lock rules are always configured on the server-side.